# JPA repository property expression

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Boot application (based on JHipster 4) I am trying to use property expressions to filter my query by attributes of related entities as described in the Spring docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

I want to get all Appointments, with a certain EmployeeAccount in their AppointmentSchedules but only receive an empty list.

```
@Repository
public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Long> {

        public List<Appointment> findByScheduledAppointmentsEmployeeAccountsId(Long id);
}
```

the relevant entities and their relationships:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appointment")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Appointment implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appointments")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<AppointmentSchedule> scheduledAppointments = new HashSet<>();

...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "appointment_schedule")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class AppointmentSchedule implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "appointment_schedule_employee_accounts", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_schedules_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_accounts_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<EmployeeAccount> employeeAccounts = new HashSet<>();

...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_account")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class EmployeeAccount implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

...

}
```

The hibernate console output when executong the query:

```
Hibernate: select appointmen0_.id as id1_1_, appointmen0_.institution_id as institut2_1_, appointmen0_.user_account_id as user_acc3_1_ from appointment appointmen0_ where appointmen0_.user_account_id=?
```

I would much appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Edit:
Please note that the Appointment table doesn't contain a column for the AppointmentSchedules as it's a OneToMany relationship. Maybe that's the reason? I thought JPA would handle that logic for me...

The table structure:

```
APPOINTMENT;
ID      ...

APPOINTMENT_SCHEDULE;
ID      APPOINTMENTS_ID    ...

APPOINTMENT_SCHEDULE_EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNTS;
EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNTS_ID    APPOINTMENT_SCHEDULES_ID

EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT;
ID    ...
```

EDIT 2:
I was able to resolve the issue. It was a classical PEBCAK error because I accidentally called a similarly named method in my service class *facepalm*. Thanks a lot to everyone who helped me! Both Gaurav Srivastav's and Dean's answers work but are not neccessary, as the original code from the question already works

Comment: schedule id is not matching correctly to appointment id as per information provided above. This causing empty resultset. Please check appointment and schedule relation again.

Answer (score 1):

You must use an underscore before referencing the nested fields. Try:

```
public List<Appointment> findByScheduledAppointments_EmployeeAccounts_Id(Long id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I already tried that and it still returns an empty  list (even though there are entries in the database)

Comment: Try the underscores with 'In' at the end. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081157/9080066

Comment: underscores are only necessary if there are name clashes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes add the word `In` to your method and provide `Set<Long>` as employeeAccountIds.

```
Set<Person> findByScheduledAppointmentsEmployeeAccountsIdIn(Set<Long> employeeIds);
```