# How to get a HashMap result from Spring Data Repository using JPQL?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've currently implemented a Ternary relationship using Map between **User**, **Shop** and **Role**.
So in my User Entity i have this mapping:

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "us_users")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false)
private int id;

@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private String uuid;

@NotBlank(message = "First name can not be empty")
@Column(name = "usFname")
private String usFname;

@NotBlank(message = "Username can not be left empty")
@Column(name = "us_lname")
private String usLname;

@NotBlank(message = "Email field can not be empty")
@ValidEmail
    @Column(name = "usEmail", unique = true)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private String usEmail;
 //this is the actual mapping
//a user can have a list of shops, but one role assigned for each shop
@ManyToMany
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "shop_fk")
    @JoinTable(name = "user_shop_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_fk"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_fk"))
    private Map<Shop, Role> shopRoleMap = new HashMap<>();
//GETTERS AND SETTERS,
}
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ro_roles")
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false)
private int id;

@Column(name = "rn_role_name")
private String roleName;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getRoleName() {
    return roleName;
}

public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
    this.roleName = roleName;
}
```

}

**Shop.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sh_shops")
public class Shop {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false)
private int id;

@NotBlank(message = "Shop name can not be left blank")
private String sh_name;

@NotBlank(message = "please provide shop icon")
private String sh_icon;

@NotBlank(message = "please fill the shop description")
private String sh_description;

@NotBlank
private String sh_tag;
//setters, getters, equals, hashCode methods.
}
```

This mapping gives me another table (**user_shop_role**) in the database that has **user_fk**,**shop_fk** and **role_fk** which is lovely.
The difficult bit is to make a Query using Spring Data JPA and get the result as a HashMap for a given user as this: HashMap<Shop,Role> for the logged in user.

At the UserRepository layer i have tried this:

interface **UserRepository** extends JpaRepository and i have this query...

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u join shopRoleMap m where key(m)= usEmail")
     public HashMap<Shop, Role> findByUser(String email);


}
```

How can i get results for a ternary relationship mapped using a Map Collection to get a list of shops and corresponding role value. More of a key,value result ?

Comment: trying getting ID of `Shop` and `Role` from the mapping table that JPA generates. Then, using these ids, get their object entity and put them in your HashMap.You cannot directly query and add results to HashMap.

Comment: If the relationship is map correctly and working. Did you try to do "SELECT m FROM ..." instead of "SELECT u FROM". So you would be returning the relation this way (m), not the user object (u).

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks , you don't know what is ternary relationship... you don't know the use case. IMHO you are just ranting...

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks please find my use case here for the deduced Mapping: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793067/how-to-represent-and-query-from-a-three-entity-relationship-in-spring-boot]

Comment: @Brother that does not work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Repository method.

```
    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository
            extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    
        @Query("SELECT key(m), value(m) FROM User u join u.shopRoleMap m" +
                " where u.usEmail = :email")
        List<Object[]> findByUserEmail(String email);
    
    }
```

- Generated query.

```
    select
        shop3_.id as id1_1_0_,
        role2_.id as id1_0_1_,
        shop3_.sh_description as sh_descr2_1_0_,
        shop3_.sh_icon as sh_icon3_1_0_,
        shop3_.sh_name as sh_name4_1_0_,
        shop3_.sh_tag as sh_tag5_1_0_,
        role2_.rn_role_name as rn_role_2_0_1_ 
    from
        us_users user0_ 
    inner join
        user_shop_role shoprolema1_ 
            on user0_.id=shoprolema1_.user_fk 
    inner join
        ro_roles role2_ 
            on shoprolema1_.role_fk=role2_.id 
    inner join
        sh_shops shop3_ 
            on shoprolema1_.shop_fk=shop3_.id 
    where
        user0_.us_email=?
```

**Update with above code plus another way**

Github repo - https://github.com/kavi-kanap/stackoverflow-6313585

Comment: @KavithanKaran i must say thank you and accept the answer as it's partially working. However on this code: `public Shop getMyShops(String email){
        Map<Shop, Role> shopRole = userRepository.findbyUserEmail(email);
        Shop shop = new Shop();
        for (Map.Entry<Shop, Role> entry : shopRole.entrySet())
        {
            shop = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println("Shop is: "+shop);
            Role role = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("The role value is: "+role.getRoleName());
        } return shop; }` i can get role but shop returns null

Comment: The updated answer still gives shop and null and entryset().getvalue() gives a cast exception

Comment: I inserted some data and played with various combinations. Unfortunately if I use `List<Object[]>` as return type, then only  `spring-data-jpa` populating both

Comment: Please how did you populate both from the returned type?

Comment: when I use `List<Object[]>` like in the updated answer, each array contains two elements, one shop and one role.

Comment: Please leave that array code here for others to reference also. Hibernate seems to not support key, value or entry keywords. That has been very cumbersome

Comment: Sorry. Just noticed your other question and I think still worth keeping that someone might know another way. I forgot to upload the code and I have updated it with my repo.

Comment: i have inspected the code on github repo and noticed that List<Object[]> in the UserRepository doesn't contribute to this working solution. The code that is actually giving the results is this snippet:

`@Transactional
    public Map<Shop, Role> getMyShops(String email){
        return userRepository.findByUsEmail(email)
                .map(User::getShopRoleMap)
                .orElse(new HashMap<>());
    }` . This code alone is giving me the results from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA has a feature called **Property Expressions** where you can access the child or related entity

For example

`List<Shop> findByUser_email(String email);`

For more details refer to this

[Spring Data JPA doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

[Sample example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080713/jpa-repository-property-expression)

Comment: If i do this i will get a list of Shops for this particular User. But what i need is to get a Shop and specific role that this User has for each single shop.

Comment: could you please add your Entity class of Shop, Role and User since it was not posted in question I gave sample answer ```findByUser_email(String email)```

Comment: i have added the requested entities.